# Socket connection opening timstamp

Tags: networking, connection, network-monitoring

Is there a way to get the timestamp when a tcp connection (tcp) was opened?
lsof and netstat are only reporting the process. Sniffers are no solution.

My application is a Business Analytics solution opening a lot of connections to the database and closing them once finished. The number of connections is very unsteady and fluctuates between 10 and several hundred. Sometimes (not reproducible) the connections are not closed properly.
I want to monitor the server for those half-open/half-closed connections so I can restart the application when the number of dead connections reach a certain limit.

Comment: I'm not posting an answer as I don't have the time to check my hypothesis right now, but i'll try this: given the PID of the process keeping that socket, check the timestamp of that socket under /proc/$PIDOF_PROGRAM/fd/$FD_NUMBER_OF_SOCKET.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The timestamp is always maximum 1min in the past. I think it's updated for every packet that goes through.